# How to set featured image from external url programmatically

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

I have already read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524931/how-to-set-featured-image-programmatically-from-url and that's not the answer to my question.

The above answer will download the image from the source and upload the library. I just want to set external URL(image URL) as the featured image without downloading my own server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `post_thumbnail_html` filter to set the post thumbnail programmatically to an external URL.

Then you wold set the image URL in a Custom Field on the post writing screen metabox (in this example with a meta key of `thumbnail_url`):

```
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'custom_thumbnail_tag_filter', 10, 3);
function custom_thumbnail_tag_filter($html, $postid, $thumbnailid) {
    if (!$thumbnailid) {
        $src = get_post_meta($postid, 'thumbnail_url', true);
        if ($src) {$html = "<img src='" . $src . "'>";}
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't test, but this is exactly what I need. I will accept after testing it.

Comment: It should be fine so long as the theme / template uses standard thumbnail functions (some theme's write and use their own.)